# Mean of variables using a reverse procedure in R

Tags: r

THIS IS MY MEAN

```
media<-by(df_02$score,df_02$sex,mean)
df_02$sex: female
[1] 3.01735
------------------------------------------------------------
df_02$sex: male
[1] 3.069552
```

NOW I HAVE TO CALCULATE THE SAME MEAN USING THEESE DATA
1) THE VARIABLE etacat IS

```
etacat<-cutpoints(df_02$age,c(15,24,34,44,54,64,74,99),destra=TRUE)  AND IT CREATES DIFFERENT RANGES OF AGE

by(df_02$score,list(df_02$sex,etacat),mean)
: female
: [15,24]
[1] 3.080624
: male
: [15,24]
[1] 3.140878

: female
: (24,34]
[1] 3.009594
: male
: (24,34]
[1] 3.100227

: female
: (34,44]
[1] 3.04165
: male
: (34,44]
[1] 3.117666

: female
: (44,54]
[1] 3.042544
: male
: (44,54]
[1] 3.092662
: female
: (54,64]
[1] 2.962814
: male
: (54,64]
[1] 3.021457

: female
: (64,74]
[1] 2.93885
: male
: (64,74]
[1] 2.849298

: female
: (74,99]
[1] 2.802057
: male
: (74,99]
[1] 2.755885
```

2) THE NUMBER OF OBSERVATIONS IN EACH AGE-RANGE ASSOCIATED TO THE SEX

```
table(df_02$sex,etacat)
[15,24] (24,34] (34,44] (44,54] (54,64] (64,74] (74,99]
female 4216 5354 4743 3748 2743 1671 716
male 3997 5093 4495 3734 2720 1788 699
```

HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS PROBLEM?

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? You already show the code that solves the problem, or at least that is how it looks to me. In addition, posting in all CAPITAL letters makes it look like your screaming, I suggest you fix this.

Comment: the problem is that I have to calculate the mean I have shown at the top using the data you can see in points 1 and 2 and not the function "mean".

Comment: @Gabriella I think you still need to clarify your question.  It isn't at all clear what your problem is.

Comment: You're right, I really don't know how to explain it better, it's just that the track is not clear at all, moreover I have to translate it in English and maybe I'm not good in it! anyway thanks for your answer!